# How to send input file data value using ajax to a php page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pdo

What I want to do is whenever a user selects a picture and click the button it will move the image to a specific folder and save the link to the database user_image column.

My problem is the actual name of the picture is not save in the database column after i click the submit button. example `Oppa/upload/` thats the value saved in the database no picture file name.

I think the value of the file didnt receive by photo.php can anyone help me solve it.

```
<input type='file' id="imageInput" name="imageInput" accept="image/*" />
<button  id="changePicture" name="changePicture">Submit</button>
```

script:

```
var data = {};
        data.imageInput = $('#imageInput').val();
        data.email = $('#email').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Oppa/view/photo.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {

            if (Number(response) == 1)
                {
                   $("#dialog-confirm-changedImage").dialog("open");
                }
            }
        });
            return false;
```

photo.php

```
<?php
include_once('../dbc/database.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imageInput']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['imageInput']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['imageInput']['tmp_name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imageInput"]["tmp_name"], "Oppa/upload/" . $_FILES["imageInput"]["name"]);
$location = "Oppa/upload/" . $_FILES["imageInput"]["name"];


if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {

        $q = "UPDATE tbl_user SET user_image = '$location' WHERE user_email= :email ";
        $query = $db->prepare($q);
        $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $results = $query->execute();
        echo "1";
}

?>
```

Comment: You can't get the image with `val`, you have to use [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: You have to use jquery ajax image uploader - http://zurb.com/playground/ajax-upload

Comment: @adeneo how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit.

Include that plugin `jquery.form.js` and then try this.

```
$('#FormID').ajaxSubmit({ //FormID - id of the form.
        type: "POST",
        url: "Oppa/view/photo.php",
        data: $('#FormID').serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {

        if (Number(response) == 1)
            {
               $("#dialog-confirm-changedImage").dialog("open");
            }
        }
    });
```

This should work. I'm using it for ajax image upload.

Thanks.

Comment: did u check, whether u get $_FILES data in photo.php.

Comment: in my web application im not using submit. i use button id# only and jquery script.

Comment: For image upload u have to use form with attr `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Also check this http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Comment: the image link is save now on the database but the actual file didnt move to upload folder. Can you help with this?

Comment: Check the uploaded folder permission as well as check the given uploaded path is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <input type='file' id="imageInput" name="imageInput" accept="image/*" />
    <button  id="changePicture" name="changePicture">Submit</button>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#changePicture").click(function(){

            var file_name=$("#imageInput").val();
            var fileName = $("#imageInput").val();
            var fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); 


            var base_url = 'Oppa/view/photo.php';

            var file_data=$("#imageInput").prop("files")[0];



            var form_data=new FormData();
            form_data.append("file",file_data);
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: base_url,
            datatype:'script',
            cache:false,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            data:form_data,
            success:function(){
            //------------
            },
            error:function(){
            //----------
            }


                });


            $("#imageInput").val('');


            })


    </script>




<?php
include_once('../dbc/database.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : "";

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "Oppa/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$location = "Oppa/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];


if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {

        $q = "UPDATE tbl_user SET user_image = '$location' WHERE user_email= :email ";
        $query = $db->prepare($q);
        $query->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $results = $query->execute();
        echo "1";
}

?>
```

don't forget to like my ans :)

Comment: and also check the upload folder permission as well

Comment: still nothing happens after i click the button

Comment: i see the request payload but nothing happens in photo.php

Comment: use echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]; die('check'); in top of your photo.php ..does it shows any value?? to check that use firebug console

Comment: the image link is save now on the database but the actual file didnt move to upload folder. Can you help with this?

Comment: are you using linux??

Comment: there is something wrong with your upload directory path or folder permission

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var data= false;
if (window.FormData) {
     data= new FormData();
}
    var email = $('#email').val();

if (formdata) {
    data.append("image", $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    data.append("email","+email+");
    data.append("fileName",$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0].name);
 }

 if (data) {
          jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "php/upload.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,//Now you attached form datas with filename also,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                       alert("Response  Data : "+data);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

jQuery("#changePicture").click(function(){

```
    var file_name=jQuery("#imageInput").val();
    var fileName = jQuery("#imageInput").val();
    var fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1); 


    var base_url = 'Oppa/view/photo.php';

    var file_data=jQuery("#imageInput").prop("files")[0];



    var form_data=new FormData();
    form_data.append("file",file_data);
    jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: base_url,
    datatype:'script',
    cache:false,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    data:form_data,
    success:function(){
    //------------
    },
    error:function(){
    //----------
    }


        });


    jQuery("#imageInput").val('');


    })
```

i hope this would help for you n don't forget to like my ans

Comment: can u explain ur answer?

Comment: on click even you are taking filename and value using id of that filed, i used  fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);to get the extension of file you can use check for images if you want ,after that i am creating new form data object and passing file properties and value using prop ,and in ajax post i am sending values of image

Comment: did you check ajax requesr in firebug..and can you tell me that how are you getting Posted file value in photo.php..and also are you giving right url of your photo.php file?

Comment: in my current code if i click upload it saves only Oppa/upload/ no filename. In urs if i click nothing happens. Can u apply formData in my script? I think that the problem in my code.