# How to solve this jQuery ajax post method undefine index problem while uploading images?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to Upload photos by using Ajax Post method,
 Here is my html and javascript code

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#multiple_upload_form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var upload = $('#images').val();
                   $.ajax({
                      type:'POST',
                       url:'album.php',
                       data:
                       {
                         upload : images  
                       },                       
                       cache:false,
                       contentType:false,
                       processData:false,
                       success:function(data)
                       {
                       $('#image_preview').html(data);
                       
                       },
                        error:function()
                        {
                            $('#image_preview').html('error');
                        }
                   });
                return false; 
            }); 
        });
   </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="album.php" name="upload_form" id="multiple_upload_form" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Album Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="aname" class="form-control" id="aname">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file">Upload Photos:</label>
            <input type="file" id="images" name="images" />
          </div>
          <div id="images_preview"></div>
      </div>
       <center class="feedback" style="display:none">Loading...</center>
          <button id="submit" name="submitt" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
     </form>
```

and this is my PHP CODING

```
if(isset($_FILES['images']['name']) )
{
    $img = $_FILES['images']['name'];

    if(!empty($img))
    {
        echo 'MaxSteel';
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Same Problem';
}
```

I am having undefine index : images 
it works fine with input type="text" but when it comes to "file" type is shows error help me solving this problem

Comment: In `upload : images` how `"images"` variable setted? I don't see it any where in your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send input file data value using ajax to a php page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837215/how-to-send-input-file-data-value-using-ajax-to-a-php-page)

Comment: Also to post images you need to use `formdata`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through this code, it may help

```
                   var data = new FormData();  
                    data.append("Avatar", file.files[0]);
                    $.ajax({
                     url: "http://192.168.1.1:2002/,
                     type: "POST",             
                     data:data,
                     contentType: false,      
                     cache: false, 
                     processData:false,  
                     success: function(data)
                      {
                     console.log(data);
                      }

                     });
```

Comment: its working but output is coming on next page i have done return false tech
but still its not working can you help me with that too

Comment: Pranay , can you please elaborate your ques.  Mate I didn't get u .... Can you provide demo in jsfiddler

Answer (score 0):

Its posible that the file is not upload becouse of some error.  You should review the parameters related to file upload as UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE, etc.

You can use var_dump($file) to see the $_FILE content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sending your data through FormData().
Try something like this:

```
var images = $("#images").get(0).files;
var formData = new FormData();

$.each(images, function(i, image) {
  data.append("images[]", image);
});
```

Then send `formData` as your $.ajax data.

Comment: Also, make your input multiple if you want to be able to send several images at once (`<input type="file" multiple />`)